# Unable to get mobile results from Google PageSpeed Insight v4 API

Tags: google-apis-explorer

Google API Explorer for new v4 Google Page Speed Insight does not allow to request results for mobile. Results for Desktop are always returned

Answer (score 1):

By specifying the query param `strategy=mobile` you can get the results for mobile This query param is specified in v2 documentation, but not in v4